# How to add flags to an APPWIDGET_CONFIGURE intent?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-widget, android-activity, intentfilter

I have an activity registered on `APPWIDGET_CONFIGURE`:

```
    <activity android:name="com.tahanot.activities.NearbyStops">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_CONFIGURE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

However this activity does not behave as expected. It opens inside of an existing stack, and when I press the Back button, it takes me to other activities instead of closing the task. Ideally, I would like the `APPWIDGET_CONFIGURE` intent to include `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` and `FLAG_ACTIVITY_MULTIPLE_TASK`.

Is it possible to specify flags in `AndroidManifest.xml`, and if not, what workaround would you suggest?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the manifest declaration that I used, following appsroxcom's idea for android:launchMode:

```
<activity
    android:name="com.tahanot.activities.NearbyStops"
    android:configChanges="orientation"
    android:label="@string/title_activity_stops_nearby"
    android:launchMode="singleTop"
    android:taskAffinity="com.tahanot.tasks.widgetConfiguration" > 
    <!-- android:launchMode makes sure the Back button doesn't navigate to another NearbyStops activity. 
         android:taskAffinity makes sure the Back button doesn't navigate to some other activity. -->
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_CONFIGURE" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider specifying launchMode attribute to the activity element.

```
<activity android:launchMode="singleTask" android:name="com.tahanot.activities.NearbyStops">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_CONFIGURE" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

As per the [official docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/tasks-and-back-stack.html),

> FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
>
> Start the activity in a new task. If a task is already running for
>   the activity you are now starting, that task is brought to the
>   foreground with its last state restored and the activity receives the
>   new intent in onNewIntent().
>
> This produces the same behavior as the **"singleTask"** launchMode value,
>   discussed in the previous section.

Since you mention you want `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` behavior so singleTask launchMode might work for you.

Comment: @apppsroxcom, Thank you very much for this pointer! This was the easiest bounty decision ever :) Actually I ended up using "singleTop" because "singleTask" didn't do what I needed. I also added a unique android:taskAffinity to this activity, to make sure it's opened on a separate task. So finally, pressing the Back button doesn't go back to any other activity.

Comment: Thanks for the bounty. It's really interesting how a combination of flags can produce different results. I am glad you found the one which worked for you. Cheers!

Comment: Strangely, adding "singleTask" to APPWIDGET_CONFIGURE caused a big problem:  The Launcher didn't place the widget on the screen after the config. It was hard to find that this flag is the cause.

Answer (score 0):

USe this java code when you start your activity

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this,
        activityname.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(intent);
```

Here you can add flag with your intent object like this.

And you can also add multiple flag.

Comment: Won't it start another activity, so I'll have two activities instead of one?

Comment: I tried putting this code in onCreate, and it does create another activity. It causes an infinite loop of activities.